# Incorrect exponent (?) when converting float from decimal representation to 32-bit binary (IEEE 754 floating point)

Tags: java, floating-point, 32-bit, ieee-754

My task was to convert a float from its decimal into its 32-bit binary representation (IEEE 754.)

Below is my attempt at solving the task; it leads to the same result that several online conversion tools yielded me, however I was told that my solution was not okay as "it encodes an incorrect exponent."

Could I get an insight into which of my steps exactly is causing this issue (if any) and why I'm still getting the correct (?) result?

==================================================================

Float (decimal representation) to convert: 6.4

Pre-decimal point positions in binary:

```
6/2 = 3 -> 0
3/2 = 1.5 -> 1
1/2 = 0.5 -> 1

=> 110
```

Decimal places in binary:

```
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 -> 1
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 -> 0
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 -> 1
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 -> 0
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 -> 1
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 -> 0
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 -> 1
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 -> 0
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 -> 1
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 -> 0
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 -> 1
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 -> 0
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 -> 1
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 -> 0
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1

=>  011001100110011001100110011001
```

Normalization:

```
110,011001100110011001100110011001 * 2^0
1,10011001100110011001100110011001 * 2^2
```

Characteristic:

```
2+127 = 129 (Exponent + Bias)

129 / 2 = 64.5 -> 1
64 / 2 = 32 -> 0
32 / 2 = 16 -> 0
16 / 2 = 8 -> 0
8 / 2 = 4 -> 0
4 / 2 = 2 -> 0
2 / 2 = 1 -> 0
1 / 2 = 0.5 -> 1

=> 10000001
```

Sign: 0 (positive)

Result:

```
01000000110011001100110011001101
```

Code snippet that supposedly causes the same problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    float input = IO.readFloat("Please enter a float!\n");
    String sign = input < 0 ? "1" : "0";
    if (input < 0) {
        input *= -1; 
    } else if (input == 0) {
        IO.println("00000000000000000000000000000000");
        return;
    }

    float preDecimalPointPositions = input - (input % 1);
    String preDecimalPointPositionsBinary = ""; 
    while (preDecimalPointPositions >= 1 ) { 
        if (preDecimalPointPositions % 2 == 0) {
            preDecimalPointPositionsBinary = "0" + preDecimalPointPositionsBinary;
        } else {
            preDecimalPointPositionsBinary = "1" + preDecimalPointPositionsBinary;
        }
        preDecimalPointPositions /= 2;
        preDecimalPointPositions = preDecimalPointPositions - (preDecimalPointPositions % 1); // Abschneiden der decimalPlacesstellen
    }

    float decimalPlaces = input % 1;
    String decimalPlacesBinary = ""; // 
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) { //
        decimalPlaces *= 2;
        if (decimalPlaces >= 1) {
            decimalPlacesBinary += "1"; 
            decimalPlaces -= 1;
        } else {
            decimalPlacesBinary += "0";
        }
    }

    int exponent; 
    if (input < 1) {
        IO.println("Negative exponents ain't allowed here! =/");
        return;
    } else {
        exponent = preDecimalPointPositionsBinary.length() - 1; 
    }
    String normalized = preDecimalPointPositionsBinary.substring(1) + decimalPlacesBinary;
    float characteristic = exponent + 127; 
    String characteristicBinary = ""; 
    while (characteristic >= 1 ) {
        if (characteristic % 2 == 0) {
            characteristicBinary = "0" + characteristicBinary;
        } else {
            characteristicBinary = "1" + characteristicBinary;
        }
        characteristic /= 2; 
        characteristic = characteristic - (characteristic % 1);
    }

    String result = sign + characteristicBinary + normalized.substring(0, 23);
    IO.println(result);
}
```

Comment: If you want to validate it compare it using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits(float)

Comment: Which online conversion tools? FWIW, I get `01000000110011001100110011001101` from Python (`python -c "import struct; print(format(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', 6.4))[0], '032b'))"`). It sounds as though the online tools you were using aren't giving the correct results.

Comment: I added code to the OP. The example that I wrote up contained an error I introduced when copy & pasting repetetive lines in the "Decimal places in dual" part (I'm really sorry for that!) It should now lead to the result you provided. Per what my instructor said, the exponent is wrong though, the second bit being a 1 doesn't make sense from what he said.

Comment: Could you translate your program to English? Despite knowing what it's supposed to do, I find it surprisingly difficult to follow without understanding the variable-names. (By the way, we say *binary*, not *dual*. We do have the word *dual*, but not with this meaning.)

Comment: Then I'm afraid your instructor is wrong. The unbiased exponent is `2`; the biased exponent is `127 + 2 = 129`, which is encoded in 8 bits as `10000001`. I agree with your analysis and result (and apparently so do several other independent sources).

Comment: @ruakh: Done. Let me know if you need the comments too.

Comment: Update: In class, we're apparently using IEEE 754-1985. The exponent is encoded as two's complement; that's probably the reason for the discrepancies my instructor was referring to.

Comment: @Max: No; the single-precision and double-precision binary interchange formats haven't changed between IEEE 754-1985 and IEEE 754-2008. In IEEE 754, the exponent has never been encoded using two's complement; it's always used a bias. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) for information about the encoding in IEEE 754-1985.

Answer (score 1):

When converting the decimal places into binary your 8th line says

```
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 -> 0
```

but then you go on with

```
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 -> 1
```

instead of

```
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 -> 0
```

the same problem exists on lines *12, 15, 18, 21 and 24*

Fixing this should then give you your correct mantissa (after normalization) giving you the correct result of

```
01000000110011001100110011001101
```

You can also check with [this IEEE 754 converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake a made when writing up this example. I fixed it in my OP now. Still, the whole procedure I use, leads to an incorrect exponent, per what my instructor says. I'll add some code to the OP that also encodes the exponent incorrectly.

Comment: @Max I can't try out the code right now but if it provides the solution that you've now corrected, it should be fine. I have no idea why your instructor would say that the first `1` *doesn't make sense*. Did he explain why? Does he know how a bias works? :D From all I know, I'd say he is just wrong and you should ask him to properly explain why he thinks that the **correct** solution is wrong.